# group multipled

Tags: abstract-algebra

In $U(10)$, $\langle3\rangle=\{3,9,7,1\}=U(10)$, for $3^1=3$, $3^2=9$, $3^3=7$, $3^4=1$, $3^5=3^4\cdot3=1\cdot3$, $3^6=3^4\cdot3^2=9$, …, $3^{-1}=7$ (since $3\cdot7=1$), $3^{-2}=9$, $3^{-3}=3$, $3^{-4}=1$, $3^{-5}=3^{-4}\cdot3^{-1}=1\cdot7=7$, $3^{-6}=3^{-4}\cdot3^{-2}=1\cdot9=9$, …

$U(10)$ is defined as all elements $>10$ and are coprime of $10$. $a$ is finite, and $\langle a\rangle$ is defined as $\{x^n\mid n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$

I understand everything in general, it's just a cyclic group as $n$ is increasing, but I have a little difficult grasping the following. 
If $3$ and $7$ are inverse to each other, $(3\mod10)(7\mod10)=21\mod10=1$, then I understand why $3^{-1}=7$, then why would $3^{-2}=9$? does that mean $9\cdot9=81$ and $81\mod10=1$, and $3^{-4}=81^{-1}$ and on $1\cdot(81\mod10)=1$ right? and $1$ is $e$, which is the identity, so this set has identity, and inverse to all elements, and it's closed and also it is associative, therefore, it's a group?

Comment: $a =3 (or 7)$  generates the cyclic group with  four elements $C_4$ ... so $a^2=a^{-2}$ or $9=9^{-1}$ (modulo $10$).

Answer (score 0):

> then why would $3^{−2}=9$?

Here's one way to see that: $3^{-2}=(3^{-1})^2=7^2=49=9\,(\operatorname{mod}10)$, since you already know that $3^{-1}=7$ in $U(10)$.

> so this set has identity, and inverse to all elements, and it's closed and also it is associative, therefore, it's a group?

Yes.